# Установка GNU Make

Tags: linux, unix, установка, solaris, gnumake

Каким образом установить GNU Make на solaris не через репозиторий?

Comment: Но зачем? Какая у вас солярка?

Comment: @pyatak, в репозитории Nexenta illumos пока что нет этой программы.

Comment: Я к тому что, вы уверены, что у вас отсутствует утилита make?!

Comment: @pyatak настал момент, что при уcтановке `openssh` команда `make install` выдает ошибки, указанные на http://hashcode.ru/questions/183869/linux-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-sh-line-9-19705-memory-fault-coredump-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-openssh, поэтому нужна утилита `gmake`.

Comment: Пробовали https://www.opencsw.org/package/gmake/ ?

Answer (score 1):

На сайте GNU скачать и скомпилировать
ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/

Либо из репозитория https://www.opencsw.org/packages/CSWgmake/